# When can I farm a boss?

Tags: borderlands-2

When farming a boss, do I need to do all of my farming before turning in the related mission, or, after turning in the mission, can I later go back to farm said boss?

Comment: I've edited your question to what I think you meant. If I'm incorrect, feel free to roll it back to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

A boss can be farmed at any point after you have reached it. Once you have beaten it, you can turn in the related quest, then save and quit, or even just leave the area and enter it again, and the boss will have respawned, ready to be farmed.

Comment: Bring friends mayhem awaits.